# css space between columns

Tags: html, css

I want to add a space between two columns. I have tried adding margin but that moves the second column under the first. Any example I have seen are for bootstrap.

Here is what I am trying to replicate

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#heading {
    border: 1px double black;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
      <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
      <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
      <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
      <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
      <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
      <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
      <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
      <li>30g of Butter</li>
      <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
      <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
      <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
      <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
      <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can see that there already are answers that probably works as a solution, but might be worthwhile for you to look into flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. It is much easier to control layouts that way. For this instance you could tell your columns to take up as much space as possible without using percentages. Should you add a third row at some point, then they would automatically adjust to take up 1/3 of the width, and it would of course work with the margins as you request for your 2 column layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would seem to be to use CSS Grids:

```css
body {
  /* Using grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* creating two columns, each of one fractional unit
     of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  /* creating two rows, the first using the keyword
     'min-content', to occupy the smallest required
     space to fit the content; the second taking one
     fractional unit of the remaining available space: */
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  /* defining named grid areas, using an ASCII art
     style approach: */
  grid-template-areas:
     "header header"
     "content content";
  /* defining a 0.5em gap between rows and 3em gap
     between columns: */
  grid-gap: 0.5em 3em;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  /* placing the <h2> element in the grid area
     named 'header' (as above): */
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
/* no specific area is assigned to the following
   elements of the grid, we leave the browser to
   place them automatically: */
```

```html
<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aj4bznod/1/).

One benefit of the above approach is that additional elements can be added and automatically placed:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "content content";
  grid-gap: 0.5em 3em;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  grid-area: header;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aj4bznod/2/).

And it's easy to reshape the grid with a media query to allow for responsive design:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  /* we use the repeat() function to place as many columns as will
     fit the space of the element (80vw, below); and sizing those
     columns using the minmax() function, with a minimum size of
     150px and a maximum of one fractional unit: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax( 150px, 1fr ));
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "content content";
  grid-gap: 0.5em 3em;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  grid-area: header;
  /* because we're using the browser to both
     auto-calculate the sizing of the columns
     and place elements within those columns,
     we're explicitly positioning the <h2> to
     begin in the first grid-track (1) and end
     in the last grid-track (-1; negative indices
     are counted from the end of the track); this
     prevents the browser from placing the content
     into newly-created columns in the header row: */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
    <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
    <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
    <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
    <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
    <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
    <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
    <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div>
  <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
  <ol>
    <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
    <li>30g of Butter</li>
    <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
    <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
    <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
    <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
    <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aj4bznod/2/).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both of your columns occupy `50%` `width`. You'll need to shrink this, allowing you to make use of the newly-created `margin`.

In the following, I've changed this `width` to `45%`, and then added `margin-right` of `10%` to the first column (with the selector `.column:first-of-type`).

Note that the columns with the additional margin still occupy the full width, as the two columns now total `90%`, leaving the `10%` for the `margin`. If you want to adjust this, simply ensure that the `margin` is equal to 100% minus the total `width` of the columns.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#heading {
  border: 1px double black;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.row {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
        <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
        <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
        <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
        <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
        <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
        <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
        <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <h3>Ingredients</h3>
      <ol>
        <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
        <li>30g of Butter</li>
        <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
        <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
        <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
        <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
        <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's are several different ways to do this, but here's my current favorite - using `display: inline-block`, plus some styles for `.column + .column` - which applies styles only to the second (and subsequent) columns in a row.  So - the columns only get 49% width, and the space between is 1%.  You can adjust these to whatever suits you, including using `calc` to have a fixed pixel width between columns if desired.

I personally don't like using `float` - while it has it's (rare) useful application, there's more elegant ways to solve this problem.

Additionally, you might consider using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to accomplish this layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#heading {
    border: 1px double black;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column + .column {
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.row {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
}

h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
      <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
      <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
      <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
      <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
      <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
      <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
      <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
      <li>30g of Butter</li>
      <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
      <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
      <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
      <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
      <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `flexbox` design implementation

Just to the **`.row`** add `display: flex;` and to the **`.column`** add `flex: 1 1 0;`

Read about [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/), [flex-grow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/),  [flex-shink](https://cssreference.io/property/flex-shrink/) and [flex-basic](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-basis/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#heading {
    border: 1px double black;
}

.column {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="heading">Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bjmYkPkjnVo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>1 pound dry spaghetti</li>
      <li>salt and freshly ground black pepper to taste</li>
      <li>6 cloves garlic, sliced thin</li>
      <li>1/2 cup olive oil (note: I prefer a regular olive oil for this recipe, as opposed to a strongly flavored extra virgin olive oil)</li>
      <li>1/4 teaspoon red pepper flakes, or to taste</li>
      <li>1/4 cup chopped Italian parsley</li>
      <li>1 cup finely grated Parmesan cheese (highly recommend Parmigiano-Reggiano)</li>
      <li>1 tablespoon of butter</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sAhUTzTJNaE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <ol>
      <li>500g of Pasta (cooked as per packet directions)</li>
      <li>30g of Butter</li>
      <li>4 Cloves of Minced Garlic (about 3-4 teaspoons)</li>
      <li>1 1/2 Cups of Cream (about 400ml)</li>
      <li>Salt and Pepper</li>
      <li>1/2 Cup of Freshly Grated Parmesan Cheese</li>
      <li>2 Teaspoons of Freshly Chopped Parsley (plus extra to garnish)</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```